# How can we script dotnet dump analyze commands?

Tags: .net, linux, debugging, coredump

When debugging windows dumps I often use cdb scripts. Such a script loads the dump, does all the necessary preparations (like setting up the symbols and loading sosex) and then:

1. Opens a log file
2. Runs the desired command
3. Closes the log file

For example:

```
...
.imgscan /l
.load e:\utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll
!lhi
.logopen "D:\tmp\dumpheap-stat.txt"
!dumpheap -stat
.logclose
```

Now with the linux dump I would like to follow the same methodology, namely - scripting and dumping results to files. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this commands to run predefined commands for `dotnet-dump analyze` and save the output to a text file:

```
/tools/dotnet-dump collect -p 1 --type Full -o $dumpfile
/tools/dotnet-dump analyze $dumpfile < /tools/dumpcommands > $dumpfile.txt
```

Put the command you need into the `dumpcommands` file, one sos command per line. The last one should be `exit`:

```
clrstack -all
clrthreads
syncblk
dumpheap -stat
exit
```

Ignore the absolute paths. I have to run it within a docker container

Comment: This is an idea. I will provide another answer to describe another way.

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem with `dotnet dump analyze` - for some reason `gcroot` does not work - it just hangs forever on our 10GB dump.

However, I saw that [Tess Ferrandez](https://www.tessferrandez.com/) was using lldb and I gave it a try and it is very good.
Here is my worklow:

1. Install lldb
2. Install dotnet-symbol
3. Run `dotnet symbol --host-only TheCoreDumpFilePath`

The last command downloads the relevant `dotnet` executable. Next we can debug:

1. `lldb -c TheCoreDumpFilePath dotnet`

Now lldb can run commands from file or given on the command line. This gives us ability to script it. Now I understand that `dotnet dump analyze` can be scripted too as shown in the respective answer.

I hope we can leverage the lldb Python API, though currently I do not see how one can invoke custom commands from it as per my other SO question here - [How to run sos extension commands through the lldb python API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71817630/how-to-run-sos-extension-commands-through-the-lldb-python-api)